# Provide an overflow menu with react native TabNavigator when there are more tabs than fit into the width of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a  Tab Navigator that is getting too crowded with the number of tabs that can fit the width of the screen.

I would like one of the tab buttons (called "More...") to pop up a list of the less frequently used tabs.

[image]

I tried to wrap the Tab Navigator in a Drawer Navigator, but I would like all the child screens launched from the Menu to also be inside the Tab Navigator so that the user always has the tabs shown above visible (and this didn't seem possible with the Drawer).

Is there a simple way to achieve this with Tab Navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, by creating a Stack Navigator for the "More" Tab. This Stack Navigator contained the overflow items for the Tab Navigator